# UIWebView: get attributes from hyperlink clicked

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have html page loaded via UIWebView. If user selects link that looks like:

```
<a webview="2" href="#!/accounts-cards/<%= item.acctno %>"></a>
```

I can get href value clicked in UIWebViewDelegate method from NSURLRequest:

```
webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
```

But how I can get attribute value from this hyperlink (webview="**2**") assuming that attribute name "webview" determined?

Comment: Check this **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775679/how-can-i-get-name-from-link**

Answer (score 0):

You can get your attribute "webview", with the help of JavaScript and after that you can send that attribute and its value to native Objective C code.

Add this JavaScript code to your HTML page inside script tag:

```
function reportBackToObjectiveC(string)
{
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("src", "callback://" + string);
    document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
    iframe = null;
}

var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
links[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
var attributeValue=links[i].webview; //this will give you your attribute(webview) value.
    reportBackToObjectiveC(attributeValue);
}, true);
}
```

after this your webViewDelegate method will call:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)wView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

{
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) 
    { 
        NSURL *URL = [request URL]; 
        if ([[URL scheme] isEqualToString:@"callback"])
        { 
            //You can get here your attribute's value.
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change href of your links. First inject javascript script, that patches your links.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView 
{

    NSString *js = @"var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');"
                    "for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {"
                    "    attribute = allElements[i].getAttribute('webview');"
                    "    if (attribute) {"
                    "        allElements[i].href = allElements[i].href + '&' + attribute;"
                    "    }"
                    "}";
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];

}
```

Links will be converted into format (note &2 in href attribute):
`<a webview="2" href="#!/accounts-cards/<%= item.acctno %>&2"></a>`
Then you can get your callback and parse you webview param value:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSArray *array = [request.URL.absoluteString componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
    if (array.count > 2) {
        NSLog(@"webview value = %@", array[1]);
    }
    return YES;
}
```